# Volume level fine on all iOS devices EXCEPT the iPhone 4. On iPhone the level is very low

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an iOS app that runs on all iOS devices. In my app, I am playing some video files. Everything works fine on all devices except for iPhone 4. On iPhone4, volume level is very low even though all other apps work with normal volume level on that device. On all other devices, volume level is fine.
Can anybody please help me with this trouble?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the source code

```
NSInteger selectedVideoTag = sender.tag;
NSString *videoPath = [self getVideoToBePlayedForButtonTag:selectedVideoTag];
NSURL *videoUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:videoPath];
NSLog(@"videoUrl = %@", videoUrl);
self.theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.theMovie];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(moviePlaybackStateChaned:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification
                                           object:self.theMovie];


[self.theMovie prepareToPlay];
[self.theMovie.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


[self.view addSubview:self.theMovie.view];
self.theMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
[self.theMovie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.theMovie setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
self.theMovie.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

[self.theMovie play];
```

Here is the code for getVideoToBePlayedForButtonTag message:

```
- (NSString *) getVideoToBePlayedForButtonTag:(NSInteger)btnTag
{
NSString *videoPath = nil;

//Trigger MixPanel events for selected button
Mixpanel *mixPanel = [Mixpanel sharedInstance];

switch (btnTag) {
    case 1:
        videoPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song_01" ofType:@"mp4"];
        break;
    case 2:
        videoPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song_02" ofType:@"mp4"];
        break;
    case 3:
        videoPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song_03" ofType:@"mp4"];
        break;
    case 4:
        videoPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"song_04" ofType:@"mp4"];
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return videoPath;
```

}

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: What framework are you using to play video?

Comment: What iOS version is on your iPhone 4?

Comment: Is your issue that the volume doesn't scale properly as it is increased? Does the volume never change with the slider or physical volume buttons? This is an outside chance but does the iPhone 4 you're testing on have another app running in the background that is hijacking the volume level? I've had instances where (app x) practically muted my iOS device and I had to kill the background running app in order to alleviate the issue.

Comment: @KhanhNguyen: I am using MpMoviePlayerController to play my video files.

Comment: @Filip: sorry, but that's a testing device and I don't have that information.

Comment: @fvrghl: I have posted the source code

Comment: you should try to get the model of iPhone 4 (there were at least two variants) -- also you should get the OS Version

Comment: also... is it on all iPhones gen 4 or is only on this testing iPhone of yours?

Comment: What are the other devices?

Comment: The issue is still occurs even if no other app is running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this problem.
In my app, I had to override the mute switch, so I added the code in AppDelegate.m

```
NSError *categoryError = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&categoryError];
```

Due to this category, iPhone 4 volume output was low.
I changed the code to

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&categoryError];
```

Now, it works fine. Though, I still can't understand why was the sound output low only on iPhone 4 and not any other device like iPad, iPhone 5.

Comment: I think the reason for this is that when you choose "PlayAndRecord" the library assumes that you are doing something like VOIP which would mean the user was holding the phone up to their ear.  In this case you would want the volume lower than if it were being held out in front of you.  You can override this by setting `kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker`

Comment: @LewisGordon: I agree with you, but I still can't understand why would the library assume so only in case of iPhone 4 and not other device.